# Установка заглушки для сайтов на сервере с OpenVPN

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, openvpn

Арендую VPS-сервер, чтобы начать немного разбираться в сетевой части и прочее. Начинаю с абсолютного нуля, поэтому не судите строго.

**Дано:** Сервер Ubuntu 20.04 с "белым" ip и работающим сервером OpenVPN.

**Задача:** Блокировать доступ к некоторым сайтам для vpn-клиентов.

*Буду рад вашей помощи и наставлениям.*

Если нужны какие-либо конфигурации - допишу по вашему запросу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За управление маршрутизацией в ядре Линукс отвечает команда `iptables`. Это очень навороченный комбайн, который можно изучать изучать бесконечно.

В вашем случае команда может быть такой:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -d <запретный_ip_адрес> -j DROP
iptables save
```

В этом скрипте запрещается пересылать пакеты с интерфейса `tun0` на заданный IP адрес. Предполагается, что `openvpn` сервер маршрутизирует пакеты, полученные от клиентов, через виртуальный интерфейс `tun0`. Если вы не устанавливали докер или ещё что-либо, что создаёт виртуальные интерфейсы, то у вас точно `openvpn` работает через `tun0`

Как узнать список интерфейсов: `ip link`

Comment: Благодарю вас за подробный ответ!
Данное правило будет блокировать пакеты, а есть ли возможность при этом прикрутить страницу заглушки? Наподобие тех, что операторы связи на заблокированные сайты ставят.